# Combo box in HTML using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a plug-in or way to duplicate the default combo box from visual studio in C#, where you can select from a list or type in a new value.  I have found several plugins to "search" or act as an autocomplete for a select element, but I want the user to be able to see all options at any time through the drop down, and add their own through the text bar (or select an option then edit it, to either make a new option or permanently alter the selected option).

Does anyone know such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this the other day, seems like it would meet your requirements: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

(NOTE: I haven't used it yet so I can't comment on how well it works)

Comment: This looks promising, I am going to take a spin and see how it works!

Comment: I had to make a couple changes to it, but this worked great, thanks :)